# Intersection of Tensor Products

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I know that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal if and only if

1. $A \subseteq B$
2. $B \subseteq A$

But, how can I apply this to show that

$(U_{1}\otimes V) \cap (U_{2}\otimes V) = (U_{1} \cap U_{2}) \otimes V$, where $U_{1}, U_{2}$ are subspaces of vector space $U$ and $V$ is a vector space.

Comment: where are $V_1,V_2$ in the equality?

Comment: Sorry, this was a mistake! It's only $V$

Comment: Okay. As a note, the result holds in general: $(U_1 \otimes V_1) \cap (U_2 \otimes V_2)=(U_1 \cap U_2) \otimes (V_1 \cap V_2)$, which is why it was uncclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a basis for $U_1 \cap U_2$, then $U_1 \setminus U_2$, and $U_2 \setminus U_1$.

Take a basis $e_1,\dots e_k$ as a basis for $U_1 \cap U_2$. Extend by $e_{k+1},\dots,e_n$ for $U_1$, and by $u_{k+1},\dots,u_m$ for $U_2$.

For the former, $U_1 \otimes V$ has basis $e_i \otimes v_i$ with $e_1, \dots ,e_n$ some basis for $U_1$ and $v_1, \dots, v_j$ some basis for $V$.

Likewise, $U_2 \otimes V$ has a basis $e_1, \dots u_m$, and the two intersect precisely at $e_1\otimes v_k, \dots e_k \otimes v_i$ as $i$ ranges through all of $V$. This is precisely the basis for the RHS.

Comment: I think I got it. The general ideia is to consider the basis for each vector space separately, then build the basis for the tensor products in the LHS and try to figure out if this basis is the same basis for the RHS ?